# curl - how to go to the next page?

Tags: php, curl

I successfully logged in using curl.

```
$ch = curl_init('http://site.com/login');
// setting posts, cookies file, headers 
curl_exec($ch);
```

Then, while logged in, I need to go to other page, lets say `http://site.com/profit` to do some stuff.

But how?
Should I run other php's script with `$ch = curl_init('http://site.com/profit')`, or is it possible to do in one file? How it should be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use curl as many times as you want in the same PHP script. Be sure to call `curl_close($ch)` between requests. Make sure that your cookie jar file (specified using CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR) is getting written to....

Comment: @Mark - There's no need to close the cURL connection in-between requests. It's actually beneficial not to since cURL will automatically set the referrer for you (if you so choose). You can save the `curl_close()` for the end of the script.

Comment: @Francois - You may be right. However, the docs for CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR says: "The name of a file to save all internal cookies to when the handle is closed, e.g. after a call to curl_close." So I jumped to the conclusion that cookies may not be available to the next request unless the first one had been closed. Are you saying that if I use curl_setopt (with CURLOPT_URL) and curl_exec multiple times between the call to curl_init and curl_close, the cookies shared between requests? I need to try that....

Comment: @Mark - Absolutely! You still need to define CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR and CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE but you don't have to close the session. I've been using cURL to scrape and automate things for years! The documentation says that if you wanted to save the cookies to file (so that you can use them again in 1 hour or tomorrow) you can use that setting for that purpose.

Comment: @Francois - That's disappointing. I've written a somewhat elaborate way to avoid using cookiejar and cookiefile for my bank account scraper, because I didn't want those cookies to touch the disk. It works great, but I was hoping that you were telling me that by leaving the session open I could simplify all that....

Comment: @Mark - It's not as disappointing as you think. The cookie file isn't written until you call `curl_close($ch);`. If you `unlink()` the file right after, it'll only be on the disk for a split second. You can try this script to see for yourself (it'll sleep for 10 seconds before writing the file): `<?php $ch = curl_init(); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt'); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt'); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.google.ca/'); curl_exec($ch); sleep(10); curl_close($ch); ?>`

Comment: It gets better. According to my testing just now, cookies are shared between requests as long as I define either CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE or CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, even if the value is `null`! I'm quite certain that when I set it to `null`, no file will be written, so this is a pretty good find.

Comment: @Mark - Interesting. I had no idea. I'm glad we both learnt something today. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: One important thing to note is that if you do multiple requests without running curl_init or curl_close between them, all options will be preserved. For example, if you set CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS with login data on the first request, those POST fields will be sent again for each additional request until you set CURLOPT_POST = false or set CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS again.

Comment: @Mark - You're right and my bad for not pointing that out. I usually set the base using `curl_setopt_array()` at the top and for every subsequent request I'll do a few `curl_setopt` to specify the URL, the verb (GET, POST, ...) and the data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initiate another CURL request for this based on the output of your previous request (whether it was successful or not)

To maintain your **'session state'** with the website, you need supply your cookies that was returned on successful authentication. The following links explains just that.

[how can i set cookie in curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560076/how-can-i-set-cookie-in-curl)

[retrieve cookie using curl, and set that cookie to user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633799/retrive-cookie-using-curl-and-set-that-cookie-to-user)