# 400 Bad Request with Curl Php SSL Authentication

Tags: php, authentication, ssl, curl

I'm getting crazy! I read a thousand post about 400 Bad Request error with Curl PHP for SSL Auth, but I never found an exhaustive answer.

So this is my snippet:

```
ini_set('display_errors','On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$username=''; // To Set
$password=''; //To Set

// CODICE DAVIDE

 $ch = curl_init();//
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://webstudenti.unica.it/esse3/Home.do');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
 $response = curl_exec($ch);

 preg_match("/Set-cookie: (.*)\n/iU", $response, $matches);
 $cookie = trim(substr($matches[1], strpos($matches[1],':')));

 $url = "https://webstudenti.unica.it/esse3/auth/Logon.do";
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username.':'.$password);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

 $response = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);

 var_dump($response);
```

What can it be? I really can't find a solution. I'm using a Windows Server with Microsoft Azure, Php version: 5.4.
Thankyou

Comment: Have you tried setting `CURLOPT_USERAGENT`? Perhaps the server needs to know it isn't a bot or crawler requesting the data?

Comment: Yes I've tried this: 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
But after this, I recive 401 unauthorized (No sense, username and pass are right)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to connect successfully using the snippet below. I added new variable `$curl` for the the second request rather than using `$ch` again.

I am getting `HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized` since the user/pass isn't set. Try this with user/password set and let me know what you find.

```
$curl = curl_init();
$url = "https://webstudenti.unica.it/esse3/auth/Logon.do";
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username.':'.$password);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
// curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY); // Might need this, but I was able to verify it works without
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.2) Gecko/20090729 Firefox/3.5.2 GTB5');

$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
var_dump($response);
```

Comment: Perfect! With curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY); it work! I Always recive 401 on the header (I don't know why) but the session work!

After that, one curiosity, if I need to navigate between page, what code I need to write and what can I drop?

Comment: @AsoStrife Glad it worked, thought it might be needed in your case but wasn't sure without user/password set. Don't forget to mark answer as correct for future visitors. Re: other question...you should be able to navigate to pages after login using additional curls. You will need to handle cookies correctly, [see this answer if needed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394068/curl-how-to-go-to-the-next-page).